# парсинг значения python

Tags: python, парсер, selenium-webdriver

Необходимо спарсить значение параметра на сайте, но как это сделать корректно я не понимаю. Делаю через webdriver:

```
driver.get("https://ru.dotabuff.com/players/100382757")
res = driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "rank-tier-wrapper")
print (res.text)
```

Возвращается пустое значение(неудивительно). Необходимо спарсить то, что выделено на скрине[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть мне необходимо получить значение "место: герой I". На каждой новой ссылке это значение будет разным, поэтому поиск по тексту отпадает. Мне нужен именно результат, который, по видимому, выдает oldtitle=

Comment: Корректней формулируйте вопрос, вы имеете в виду вам нужен контент атрибута oldtitle? Если да, то тогда так и пишите, т.к. `oldtitle=` ничего выдавать не может.

Comment: Могу писать некорректно, ввиду своей неопытности. За это прошу извинить. Да, мне нужен контент атрибута oldtitle=, и я не знаю, как его получить.